# Where does 5774 fall in the 19-year cycle?

Tags: calendar

We are in a leap year, as indicated by the presence of Adar Bet.  Leap years occur every third, sixth, eighth, eleventh, fourteenth, seventeenth and nineteenth years in the cycle.  So how to tell *which* leap year we are in?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6376/759

Comment: 5765, 5768, 5771, and 5774 were all leap years. Can you figure it out now?

Comment: The Tur has a handy-dandy chart of the year-cycles.

Comment: @DoubleAA isn't this a duplicate of that?

Comment: @YEZ please see my preceding comment (ccing you because you're pingable, and the more eyes on my question the better).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5774 is the 17th year in the 304th cycle of the moon. [See page 7 of this link](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/5770dinim/5770dinim01.pdf)

If you divide 5774 / 19 the answer is 303 with a remainder of 17.

Comment: You can take the any year [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 19 to determine where in the cycle we are in. This is actually why we use 0368BEH instead of, for example, 0258ADG or 0258BDG. Conveniently, 5700 mod 19 = 0, so for the near future you only have to deal with the latter two digits.