# When was the first Jewish leap year?

Tags: calendar, yetziat-mitzrayim, leap-years

What number year within the 19-year cycle was the year of Yetziyat Mitzrayim -- if that was the mechanism used in the midbar to keep Pesach in the Spring

and alternatively, if the cycle wasn't what was used to determine the leap year in the midbar (the quote from the Rambam [here](https://www.ou.org/holidays/files/r-manning-leap-year-issues.pdf) indicates that the cycle, itself, didn't determine the leap month back then) then when was the first leap month added?

Comment: The Exodus was in 2448 ≡ [16 mod 19](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36513/where-does-5774-fall-in-the-19-year-cycle#comment95126_36517). But I agree that cycle wasn't used back then.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm also reading this answer which seems to indicate that leap months followed a cycle pre-Egypt https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101606/1362

Comment: Doesn't this cycle only apply after the calculated calendar? Back then didn't they decide each year?

Comment: @Kazibácsi but on average it's still going to be 7 out of 19 years.